# Upgrading Neo4J from 2.0.1 to 2.0.4 via Homebrew

Tags: neo4j, homebrew

I want to upgrade Neo4J from version 2.0.1 to 2.0.4 both on my Mac (where it was installed using `brew`) and on my Linux machine.

What's the best way to do that? Is it better to just copy the new files manually or is there another way to do it?

Also, how can I change the path for neo4j to the new folder from `neo4j-community-2.0.1` to `neo4j-community-2.0.4` in homebrew if I do the update manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think homebrew natively supports install anything but the latest version of a package.  There is a homebrew/versions tool that you can use along with a lot of other solutions here:

[Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

There doesn't seem to have ever been a homebrew formula for 2.0.4 (probably because it was a bug fix that came after 2.1 came out).  Here is the most recent formula for 2.0.3:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/387c92e63b9db59b0a9958c4f1500be75c0e4d0c/Library/Formula/neo4j.rb

You could try tweaking that.  You probably just need to change the version to 2.0.4 and change the sha1 hash.  You can get the hash by downloading the package and running the `shasum` command on the file, which can be downloaded here:

http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

If you don't want to have to go through all that trouble, you can also just download the package from that last link and run neo4j from inside that.  It's pretty straightforward and I personal prefer that because it makes it easier to find the `conf` and `data` files when I need to work on them